# How to get dict item group to cover all keys in python?

Tags: python, group-by, associations

I have a python `dict` shown below:

```
d = {
    'AAA':['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'BBB':['b', 'c', 'd'],
    'CCC':['d', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'x'],
    'DDD':['d', 'f', 'g'],
    'EEE':['g','d','h','o']
}
```

The `dict` value is items.

I want to get the items group to cover all `dict` keys.

i.e. `('b', 'c')` group exists in `AAA` and `BBB`. So this group can cover `AAA` and `BBB`.

one possible result is as below.

```
{('b', 'c'): ['AAA', 'BBB'],
 ('d', 'f'): ['CCC', 'DDD'],
 ('d', 'g'): ['EEE', 'DDD'],}
```

All `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`, `DDD`, `EEE` can be covered by `('b', 'c')`, `('d', 'f')` and `('d', 'g')`.

FP-Growth and Apriori algorithm may work. I tried `FP-Growth` as below, But still cannot get such result.

```
import pyfpgrowth

d = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['b', 'c', 'd'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'x'],
    ['d', 'f', 'g'],
    ['g','d','h','o']
]
#Use find_frequent_patterns to find patterns in baskets that occur over the support threshold:
patterns = pyfpgrowth.find_frequent_patterns(d, 2)
print(patterns)
```

The output is

```
{('b',): 2,
 ('b', 'c'): 2,
 ('c',): 2,
 ('d',): 4,
 ('d', 'f'): 2,
 ('d', 'g'): 2,
 ('d', 'h'): 2,
 ('f',): 2,
 ('g',): 2,
 ('h',): 2}
```

FP-Growth and Apriori algorithm cannot solve the problem directly. Apart from this, their performance is not good.

Do we have any algorithm or lib to do such task?

Comment: You said, "FP-Growth and Apriori algorithm may work". Why didn't you try? If you have tried, then show us.

Comment: What are you planning to use the key for? Usually a dictionary is for looking up values by the (full) key.

Comment: @Yusufsn, I do tried, I will add the result to the topic.

Comment: @KlausD. I will generate the items group to cover all keys. That is the objective.

Comment: Presumably you want the smallest set of groups.  Must every group have size 2, or all the same size?

Comment: @DavisHerring. Acceptable in any size. No need to be equal size

Comment: @ybdesire: Then wouldn’t singletons always cover at least as much as any larger group?

Comment: @DavisHerring singleton is special case. The best result is generate smallest groups, so singleton should be removed.

Comment: @ybdesire: But a singleton is the smallest group possible, and also the most useful since it covers any dictionary key covered by any larger group that contains the single value.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes you are right. Do you have any suggestion to get the result ?

Comment: This is the [hitting set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation), so if I had a *good* algorithm I wouldn’t be first posting it here!

Comment: @DavisHerring Thank you for helping me to point out that this is the "hitting set problem".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution using pandas.
The length of the groups containing the keys can be limited between min and max value.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'AAA':['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'BBB':['b', 'c', 'd'],
    'CCC':['d', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'x'],
    'DDD':['d', 'f', 'g'],
    'EEE':['g','d','h','o']
}


for k, i in d.items():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(i), index=[k])
    df1[:]=True
    try:
        df=df.append(df1, sort=True)
    except:
        df=df1.copy()
```

Just to know what is going on here, the intermediate dataframe df is a table like this:

```
    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    o    x
AAA True True True NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
BBB NaN  True True True NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
CCC NaN  NaN  NaN  True True True NaN  True NaN  True
DDD NaN  NaN  NaN  True NaN  True True NaN  NaN  NaN
EEE NaN  NaN  NaN  True NaN  NaN  True True True NaN
```

You'll then transpose this dataframe and extract the groups as in the code below; you can set limits to the number of items you want in each group of keys.
There's not limits on the number of elements covering each group. So a group of keys can be covered by a single element (s. results).
This is a possible solution since, unless other contraints are specified, there're many other solutions to your problem. 
The code also check whether all keys are covered by the solution with the constrains given.

```
# set min and max number of items in each tuple of keys
min = 2
max = 3

df=df.fillna(False)

dft=df.transpose()

dft['sum'] = dft[:].sum(axis=1)

dft1 = dft[(dft['sum']>=min) & (dft['sum']<=max)]
dft1 = dft1.drop('sum', axis=1)

g = lambda a,b:[x for x, y in zip(tuple(a), tuple(b)) if y == True]

c=dft1.columns
dft1['groups'] = dft1.apply(lambda x: g(c, x), axis=1)
dft1['groups'] = dft1['groups'].apply(tuple)

grouped=dft1.groupby('groups')

final = dict()
key_covered = []
for key, item in grouped:
    lkey = list(key)
    if not set(lkey).issubset(key_covered):
        final[key] = tuple(item.index)
        key_covered += key

print('Result:')
for k,i in final.items():
    print(i, end=': ')
    print(k)

print('Keys covered')
print(key_covered)

# Check if result covers all keys
if not set(key_covered).issubset(d.keys()):
    print('Initial dict is not covered with this constrains')
```

With min number of items in each keys group equal to 2 and max number 3, the final result will be:

```
Result:
('b', 'c'): ('AAA', 'BBB')
('f',): ('CCC', 'DDD')
('h',): ('CCC', 'EEE')
Keys covered
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'CCC', 'EEE']
```

If min number of items in each keys group equal to 2 and max number 4, the final result will be:

```
Result:
('b', 'c'): ('AAA', 'BBB')
('d',): ('BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE')
Keys covered
['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE']
```

Comment: That final result looks a lot like the input.

Comment: thanks for the help. but the result is not what i need. would you check the "one possible result is as below" part at above for more details about the expected result?

Comment: @DavisHerring you're kind to say the result looks a lot like the input :) Actually it ends up being the input. You're right.

Comment: @ybdesire I changed the code to include a constrain on the number of items in each group of keys. Without more constraints there're many possible solutions (including the extreme solution of the input itself). Given that you didn't set a boundary on the length of each group covering the keys, I consider singleton  also to be ok. If I'm wrong and you need more constraints, please let me know in the comments and I'll try my best